# Can you use the LAN option to connect your phone to an Expo project when using WSL2?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have created a new app using `expo init <app_name>`.
When I lunch it using `sudo expo start`, the LAN does not work, I get `Connection response timed out`

My setup is WSL2 + Ubuntu 20.04, and the PC has no WiFi, but my phone is connected to the same home network via WiFi.

I've tried many of the solutions provided by posts here and other forums, including some scripts to forward ports, but none of them worked. The tunnel option does work